# Adding libcurl to FireBreath broke the wix installer

Tags: wix, libcurl, firebreath

Ever since I added the libcurl to my FireBreath project it fails to build the wix installer with the following warnings:

```
heat.exe : warning HEAT1108: The command line switch 't:' is deprecated. Please use 't' instead.
heat.exe : warning HEAT5150: Could not harvest data from a file that was expected to be a SelfReg DLL: MyPlugin\build-2013\bin\MyPlugin\Debug\npMyPlugin.dll. If this file does not support SelfReg you can ignore this warning. Otherwise, this error detail may be helpful to diagnose the failure: Unable to load file: MyPlugin\build-2013\bin\MyPlugin\Debug\npMyPlugin.dll, error: 126
```

and errors:

```
MyPlugin\build-2013\projects\MyPlugin\npMyPlugin_auto.wxs(8): error LGHT0204: ICE38: Component cmpDFE9DEB969CA844E4DE61869CCB6F7DD installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\light.exe" -sw1076 -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixUIExtension -out MyPlugin/build-2013/bin/MyPlugin/Debug//MyPlugin.msi MyPlugin/build-2013/projects/MyPlugin/MyPluginInstaller.wixobj MyPlugin/build-2013/projects/MyPlugin/npMyPlugin_auto.wixobj
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 204.
```

Nothing changed other than adding the curl library.
Here's how I added the library:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libcurl_imp.lib)
```

I searched but all I could find are posts related to the wix files, which I haven't touched.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the built-in curl support.

http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Libraries

But the most common WiX problem (with FireBreath) is that it cannot find the linked DLL from PATH environment value. Even the library is mentioned in Firebreath makefiles, you need to ensure that the DLL is available in PATH. Otherwise Wix does not find it and cannot build the installer.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that, though it says it's "experimental". In any case I've decided to go with a different solution for http so I won't be using that. The tip regarding the common WiX problem is good, I'll be sure to remember that for the future.